# Maven/Gradle List out the Compiled Classes

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build

`Maven` and `Gradle` both uses incremental build by default if I am not mistaken.

- For fresh/first build, It would build all class files.
- Upon next build without any change, it doesn't build any class files.
- If I modify the A.java, it would recompile the module.

**Is there any option to get the list of class files that are compiled in this build?**

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441013/getting-a-build-logfile-by-maven), which discusses how to configure Maven to log its build activity.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, any specific option to print only `compiled` classes. `Info` doesn't print that info. Dumping in `debug` mode will not give much useful information about my query.

Answer (score 1):

How about `maven.compiler.verbose` property?

If I set it to true I get either

```
% mvn compile -Dmaven.compiler.verbose=true 2>&1 | grep class
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

or if I modify the `A.java` file

```
% mvn compile -Dmaven.compiler.verbose=true 2>&1 | grep class | grep wrote
[wrote RegularFileObject[/tmp/mvn-compile/target/classes/A.class]]
[wrote RegularFileObject[/tmp/mvn-compile/target/classes/B.class]]

... and other similar output
```

You can also get little bit deeper into your OS and trace (e.g., `strace` on some Linux distros) `write` syscalls (posix compliant platforms) and grep the `.class` files that are being written.

You can also use option `-Dmaven.compiler.fork=true` which forks `javac` (which used to be a default but is not anymore apparently). You can trace the arguments of javac, which are passed through a temporary file (which exists only during the execution of javac, for instance it is `/tmp/org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler2179201625419771061arguments`). You can also `cat` this file and see which files are passed to javac to be recompiled. In my case (Mac OS X), this file is stored in `/tmp` and to output it, I naively run

```
% cd /tmp; while true; do ls org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler* | xargs cat; sleep 1; done
zsh: no matches found: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler*
zsh: no matches found: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler*
zsh: no matches found: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler*
"-d"
"/tmp/mvn-compile/target/classes"
"-classpath"
"/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.3.0/config-1.3.0.jar:/Users/stepan/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.4/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar:"
"-sourcepath"
"/tmp/mvn-compile/src/main/java/A.java"
"/tmp/mvn-compile/src/main/java/B.java"
"-s"
"/tmp/mvn-compile/target/generated-sources/annotations"
"-g"
"-verbose"
"-nowarn"
"-target"
"1.8"
"-source"
"1.8"
"-encoding"
"UTF-8"
```

Another question is how Maven decides which class to recompile. If I remember it correctly, it used to be based on a comparison of timestamps of `.java` files vs their `.class` matching files. If `.java` file was newer, then it was added to javac to be recompiled. However, I can see right now, it's much more complicated and to understand the reasons, I would recommend debug maven execution and look at `AbstractCompilerMojo.java` and its `execute` method.
For instance, if there is `package-info.java` file in my sources directory, all the classes are always recompiled even if they are not changed.